# How to implement Angular2 routing and SPA (MVC 4)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angular2-routing

My existing application structure looks like this:

Web
 
    --- Scripts
 
      ---- AngularApp
         ---- Page1
 
         ---- Page2
 
         ---- Page3
 
View
    --- Home
        --- Page1

I have tried the two methods of:

1. HTML5
2. Hash based routing.

However, if I refresh the URL from within the browser, I get a 404 error.

Please guide me on how to implement routing.

My URL:

http://localhost/web/Home/Page1

Web - Subdomain

If I will try to open http://localhost/web/AngularApp/Page2 I get 404 error.

So, please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution with first method HTML5. Just need to update "web.config" for URL Rewrite.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="AngularApp MiniSPA">
<match url="^AngularApp/(.+)"/>
<action type="Rewrite" url="AngularApp/Home"/>
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

And also added base href on Home.cshtml

```
<base href="/AngularApp">
```

Thanks